# Select nth value of NSArray

Tags: objective-c, swift

How would I go about selecting the nth values of an array and adding them to another array.

For example, if i have an NSArray which has 100 objects and I want to add every 5th object? I understand how to select the 5th object and how to add to a new array etc, but just looking for the best way to do this. This is for image manipulation, so will be dealing with arrays of up to 2m pixel values.

Is the best way to just use for loops?

Comment: You tagged both Objective-C and Swift. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using striding:

```
    .stride(to: 100, by: 5)
```

So to create a new array:

```
    Array(0.stride(to: 10, by: 2).map( { myArray[$0] }))
```

UPDATE: As Leo Dabus points out, the above will start at element 0 (and take every 2nd). If you want to start at the 5th and take every 5th, you would use:

```
    Array(4.stride(to: 100, by: 5).map( { myArray[$0] }))
```

Comment: that will return the first object. You can fix it starting from 4. `4.stride(to: 100, by: 5)`

Answer (score 0):

Using loops is pretty good: they are easy to read, and they are about as efficient as anything else that you may want to use for this purpose. The only optimization to the `for` loop approach is to reserve a specific number of elements upfront, because you know how many elements you are going to write.

If you are going to make the same selection from multiple arrays (e.g. processing an array of arrays), consider creating `NSIndexSet`, and applying it with `objectsAtIndexes` to perform the selection. This may give your code slightly better readability, because the `for` loop for creating indexes would be separate from the process of selection.

Finally, if you need to optimize for speed, and your arrays store wrapped primitives, consider using plain arrays instead of `NSArray` to avoid wrapping and unwrapping. This has a potential of giving you the most improvement, because by eliminating additional memory accesses for unwrapping it would also significantly improve locality of reference, which has crucial importance for cache use optimization.